# While sqoop import an error occurred "Converting the varchar value to JDBC data type DECIMAL"

Tags: sqoop

### Scenario:

When I enter the sqoop import query I am getting as below:

### Error:

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~/sqoop-1.1.0/bin$ ./sqoop-import --driver 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.xx.xx;database=HadoopTest;user=xxxxx;password=xxxxxx' --table PersonInfo1 --target-dir /data/PersonInfoData --check-column email --incremental append --compress11/12/10 15:52:50 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
11/12/10 15:52:50 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM PersonInfo1 AS t WHERE 1=0
11/12/10 15:52:50 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM PersonInfo1 AS t WHERE 1=0
11/12/10 15:52:51 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_HOME is /home/hadoop/hadoop-0.21.0/bin/..
11/12/10 15:52:51 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/e8d9b5cc0800d8cde97f533f477a8ebd/PersonInfo1.jar
11/12/10 15:52:51 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An error occurred while converting the varchar value to JDBC data type DECIMAL.
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.initIncrementalConstraints(ImportTool.java:235)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:345)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:423)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:83)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:170)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:196)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:205)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An error occurred while converting the varchar value to JDBC data type DECIMAL.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DDC.convertStreamToObject(DDC.java:473)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ServerDTVImpl.getValue(dtv.java:2474)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DTV.getValue(dtv.java:176)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Column.getValue(Column.java:113)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:1981)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:1966)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getBigDecimal(SQLServerResultSet.java:2596)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.getMaxColumnId(ImportTool.java:187)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.initIncrementalConstraints(ImportTool.java:230)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:459)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:728)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DDC.convertStringToObject(DDC.java:285)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DDC.convertStreamToObject(DDC.java:436)
    ... 16 more
```

### Question:

Why it is happening? Pls suggest me solution to remove this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a field in your SQL Server table that is defined as varchar, but has some of the records as numbers.  It may be assigning the data type to the field it decides you want.

Comment: I think there is some  issue. "An error occurred while converting the varchar value to JDBC data type DECIMAL." The program seems to convert varchar into Decimal somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Its might be because you trying to convert varchar into float or decimal.
Its DataType issue check your column datatype in database and in your java code.